# Why does c2 (column 2) in my output always print out "2", when it should output "0" instead? (C language)

Tags: c, matrix

Please try my code and input 3 for all the inputs. I wrote code to make and visualize matrix of rows and columns. ALL column 2 outputs the number "2", when I expect "0" to be outputted.

I inputted 4 rows and 4 columns, I expected "0" to be the output for everything. Instead, I got "2" on ALL column 2 outputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[0][0];
int array2[0][0];


void createMatrix(int matrixx, int matrixy);
void createMatrix2(int matrixx, int matrixy);

void printMatrix(int rows, int columns);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int x;
    int whatMatrixAreWeOn = 1;
    int iRows;
    int iColumns;
    int matrix1x;
    int matrix1y;
    int matrix2x;
    int matrix2y;
    printf("Input how many rows you want for matrix %d: ", whatMatrixAreWeOn);
    scanf("%d", &iRows);
    printf("Input how many columns you want for matrix %d: ", whatMatrixAreWeOn);
    scanf("%d", &iColumns);
    createMatrix(iRows, iColumns);
    printMatrix(iRows, iColumns);
    whatMatrixAreWeOn += 1;
    printf("Input how many rows you want for matrix %d: ", whatMatrixAreWeOn);
    scanf("%d", &iRows);
    printf("Input how many columns you want for matrix %d: ", whatMatrixAreWeOn);
    scanf("%d", &iColumns);
    createMatrix(iRows, iColumns);
    printMatrix(iRows, iColumns);

    return 0;
}


void printMatrix(int rows, int columns)
{
    int i;
    int x;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < columns; x++)
        {
            /*
            NOTE: i = row, x = column

            if row(i) = 3, and column(x) = 2
                x x
                x x
                x x
            */
            printf("r%d, c%d: %d ", i + 1, x + 1, array[i][x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


}

void createMatrix(matrixx, matrixy)
{
    int i;
    int x;
    for (i = 0; i < matrixx; i++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < matrixy; x++)
        {
            array[matrixx][matrixy] = 0;
        }
    }

}

void createMatrix2(matrixx, matrixy)
{
    int i;
    int x;
    for (i = 0; i < matrixx; i++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < matrixy; x++)
        {
            array2[matrixx][matrixy] = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: These declarations int array[0][0];
int array2[0][0]; are invalid. You may not specify zero elements in an array declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Vlad from Moscow pointed out: You can't change the size of an array after you initialized it, so your `array` and `array2` will always have size 0. You can make it a pointer to a heap object though. Consider this:

```c
void createMatrix(int matrixx, int matrixy) {
    array = calloc(matrixx * matrixy, sizeof **array);
}
```

This will automatically write 0 to each element.

**EDIT:** As @ryyker kindly reminded me - you need to make `array` and `array2` into pointers:

```c
int* array;
int* array2;

// And you have to reference it with
int element = array[x * y];
```

Otherwise there is the possibility to make a two dimensional array out of integers with:

```c
    int** array;
    
    // in your create function
    array = calloc(5, sizeof *array);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) array[i] = calloc(3, sizeof **array);

    // and you reference it like you already did
    int element = array[x][y];
```

Comment: Your function requires a pointer variable as the lvalue of the `calloc` call.  `int array[0][0];` was created as a 2D array, not a pointer.